# Arch linux: systemd boot menu with arch kernel and lts kernel

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, boot, linux-kernel, boot-loader

I would like to be able to choose kernel on boot up. I have installed arch default and lts kernel. I am using **systemdboot** as boot loader.

But when I start my notebook it directly starts booting without showing any menu. When I run `uname -r` I get:

```
5.9.0-arch1-1
```

in `/boot/loader/entries/` I have two files:

*arch.conf*

```
title Arch Linux
linux /vmlinuz-linux
initrd /intel-ucode.img
initrd /initramfs-linux.img
options root="LABEL=arch_os" rw
```

and *arch-lts.conf*

```
title Arch Linux (LTS)
linux /vmlinuz-linux-lts
initrd /intel-ucode.img
initrd /initramfs-linux-lts.img
options root="LABEL=arch_os" rw
```

in `/boot` I have:

```
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4.0K 11. pro 11.08  EFI/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  28M 26. led 16.39  initramfs-linux-fallback.img*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7.6M 26. led 16.39  initramfs-linux.img*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  28M 25. led 16.19  initramfs-linux-lts-fallback.img*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7.7M 25. led 16.19  initramfs-linux-lts.img*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3.5M 19. lis 08.58  intel-ucode.img*
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K 27. led 19.34  loader/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K 29. čec  2020 'System Volume Information'/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8.6M 26. led 16.39  vmlinuz-linux*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6.2M 25. led 16.19  vmlinuz-linux-lts*
```

When I run `bootclt` I get:

```
System:
     Firmware: UEFI 2.60 (Lenovo 0.6032)
  Secure Boot: disabled
   Setup Mode: setup
 Boot into FW: supported

Current Boot Loader:
      Product: systemd-boot 245.7-1-arch
     Features: ✓ Boot counting
               ✓ Menu timeout control
               ✓ One-shot menu timeout control
               ✓ Default entry control
               ✓ One-shot entry control
               ✓ Support for XBOOTLDR partition
               ✓ Support for passing random seed to OS
               ✓ Boot loader sets ESP partition information
          ESP: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/734e58b8-003a-4faf-bb75-338274e3fe64
         File: └─/EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi

Random Seed:
 Passed to OS: yes
 System Token: set
       Exists: yes

Available Boot Loaders on ESP:
          ESP: /boot (/dev/disk/by-partuuid/734e58b8-003a-4faf-bb75-338274e3fe64)
         File: └─/EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi (systemd-boot 245.7-1-arch)
         File: └─/EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi (systemd-boot 245.7-1-arch)

Boot Loaders Listed in EFI Variables:
        Title: Linux Boot Manager
           ID: 0x0002
       Status: active, boot-order
    Partition: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/734e58b8-003a-4faf-bb75-338274e3fe64
         File: └─/EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi

        Title: Windows Boot Manager
           ID: 0x0000
       Status: active, boot-order
    Partition: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/734e58b8-003a-4faf-bb75-338274e3fe64
         File: └─/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

        Title: Linux-Firmware-Updater
           ID: 0x0001
       Status: active, boot-order
    Partition: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/734e58b8-003a-4faf-bb75-338274e3fe64
         File: └─/EFI/arch/fwupdx64.efi

Boot Loader Entries:
        $BOOT: /boot (/dev/disk/by-partuuid/734e58b8-003a-4faf-bb75-338274e3fe64)

Default Boot Loader Entry:
        title: Arch Linux
           id: arch.conf
       source: /boot/loader/entries/arch.conf
        linux: /vmlinuz-linux
       initrd: /intel-ucode.img
               /initramfs-linux.img
      options: root="LABEL=arch_os" rw
```

How can I achieve state in which I can choose kernel on boot in bootmenu ? How can I make boot menu show on first place ?

If you need any more information comment under this post and I will add them soon as possible.
Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to set **timeout** parameter in `/boot/loader/loader.conf`:

```
default arch.conf
timeout 5
console-mode max
editor no
```